# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python

I'm solving Leetcode algorithm "Middle of linked list" but when I try to print the output I keep getting error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [17], in <cell line: 24>()
     22 # head = ListNode(head)
     23 s = Solution()
---> 24 s.middleNode(head)

Input In [17], in Solution.middleNode(self, head)
     10 slow = head
     11 # Travel until the fast pointer reaches
     12 # the last node or None
---> 13 while fast != None and fast.next != None:
     14     # slow pointer moves 1 node
     15     slow = slow.next
     16     # fast pointer moves 2 nodes

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'
```

here is my code:

```
# 876. Middle of a linked list
# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
class Solution(ListNode):
    def middleNode(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        fast = head
        slow = head
        # Travel until the fast pointer reaches
        # the last node or None
        while fast != None and fast.next != None:
            # slow pointer moves 1 node
            slow = slow.next
            # fast pointer moves 2 nodes
            fast = fast.next.next
        return slow


head = [1,2,3,4,5]
s = Solution()
s.middleNode(head)
```

I've tried this at the end:

```
head = [1,2,3,4,5]
head = ListNode(head)
s = Solution()
s.middleNode(head)
```

but I could only get this which seems like a memory address:

```
<__main__.ListNode at 0x7fa0683a2b50>
```

what I expect that is the list starts from the value at the middle of the list:

```
[3,4,5]
```

Comment: You give a list instead of a "ListNode" as "head" argument to "middleNode" call. You have to build the linked list of "ListNode" objects first.

Comment: you need to create linked list first